# firing all keydown/up events in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

my problem... I can't seem to fire all the keydown events.

I am using an [enter] and [esc] keydown event to update/refresh or exit/refresh data in some html tables

there are static table cells and dynamic table cells, populated based on the users search-term input

dynamic tables come from a $.each loop but the div structures are exactly the same ( and div id's are unique ). in both cases the resulting table cell is...

```
<td class="edit"><div contenteditable="true" id="XYZ">[value]</div></td>
```

the keydown functions are exactly the same....

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#divA").keydown(function (e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // send data to server          
        // refresh stuff
    } 
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        // refresh stuff
    }       
    });

    $("#divB").keydown(function (e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // send data to server
        // refresh stuff        
    } 
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        // refresh stuff
    }       
    });
```

the separate functions posting date to the server are the same. and the php to update the database is the same also. and both have the same mysql data structure `double, yes null, zero default`. divB exists with data in it and `alert($("#divB").text());` shows the values that would be used in the ajax update.

but I guess none of that matters because I have narrowed the problem to here...

in divA, keydown stops the [enter] line-break and runs the code

in divB, keydown does not stop the [enter] line-break and none of the code runs

the only difference is divA is static and divB is generated in javascript. how can I get the divB keydown function to run ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since some of the divs are dynamic you can't use `keydown`  to bind events to them. this method will only bind to existing divs when the page loads.

What you need is to use [jquery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [jquery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (on is newer so if your jquery version support it, better to use it).